# Derivative of $x^x$ using partial differentiation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The derivative of $x^x$ wrt $x$ can be found using logarithmic differentiation.

Can we find the same using partial differentiation?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by partial differentiation ? Taking logs is how I would do this problem.

Comment: @Chinny84. I have he feeling that you have absent on the site for a while. If this is true, then *Welcome back home !*

Comment: Indeed @ClaudeLeibovici not really answering or doing much interaction other than upvoting - Thank you for the welcome back :)! But I see somethings never change ..

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217818/1242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this is what you mean.

Let $f(x,y)=x^y$. Then $f_1(x,y)=yx^{y-1}$, $f_2(x,y)=x^y\log x$. If we set $g(t)=f(t,t)$ then $g'(t)=f_1(t,t)+f_2(t,t)=t^t(1+\log t)$.

Observe though that you still need logarithmic derivation in order to know that the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x\log a$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need logarithmic differentiation, just chain rule, to get $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a^x:=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \exp(x\log a)=\exp(x\log a)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x\log a)=\dots$ ditto for $x^x$, but that is another can of worms.

Comment: Alex can u expand also on a^x to complete it

Comment: User i see chain rule is great!